# controlling execution order with jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, asynchronous

This should be simple but a lot of older answers on SO seem to get it slightly wrong. I want to be able to *load* a library, some plugin, and some code asynchronously, but be certain that they're *executing* in order.

This sort of thing doesn't work, because the scripts execute whenever they're loaded, which might not be in the order listed:

```
if (someCondition) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "theLibrary.js",
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("library loaded and executed");
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: "thePlugin.js",
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("plugin loaded and executed");
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: "theCode.js",
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("code loaded and executed");
    }
  });
}
```

One first stab at this might be to nest the dependencies in the callbacks like this:

```
if (someCondition) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "theLibrary.js",
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("library loaded and executed");
        $.ajax({
          url: "thePlugin.js",
          dataType: "script",
          cache: true,
          success: function(data) {
            console.log("plugin loaded and executed");
            $.ajax({
              url: "theCode.js",
              dataType: "script",
              cache: true,
              success: function(data) {
                console.log("code loaded and executed");
              }
            });
          }
        });
    }
  });
}
```

Now that solves the *execution* problem (although it's hell to read) but the problem is now that the `loading` of the second and third scripts is held up while the previous script is being loaded and executed. In other words, the loading and execution aren't fully decoupled.

There doesn't seem to be an option in `.ajax` or its shorthand stepchild `.getScript` to delay execution. From the docs:

> dataType: "script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text.

In other words, loading and execution seem to be fully coupled. Is there a clean way to handle this type of situation of deeply nested dependencies, using only jquery, **without an additional script loading library**?

Comment: Take a look at [jQuery Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) or you could try using a script loader such as RequireJS or LABjs or YepNope...

Comment: Thanks, I have. But don't see how they address this question. Deferreds definitely provide a more readable way of rewriting example 2, but it seems to me that the coupling of loading and execution remains the same, due to the very nature of `.ajax`. If the referenced script is always executed before any ajax callbacks/deferreds are called/resolved, then loading and execution are still chained together at each step of the process. Is a way to call for script #2 to be loaded BEFORE script #1 has finished executing?

Comment: You could load all your scripts as text files , put it in strings. and when all the dependencies are resolved , manually create script tags , and inject the script strings into the script tags as innerText properties of the respective script tags , then append the script tags to the DOM. But i dont think it would scale , especially  when libraries that handle all that stuff already exist.

Comment: sure you can use deferreds just dont chain them

Comment: @camus That's definitely a thought. I don't need it to scale :) Can you provide this as an answer, with code?

Comment: @ianace How does using deferreds keep ajax-called scripts from executing immediately? Please provide a code example?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async#series) series method though originally for Node.js it works in browser as well.

So basically you can do something like

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        // do some stuff ...
        callback(null, 'one');
    },
    function(callback){
        // do some more stuff ...
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
],// optional callback
function(err, results){
        // results is now equal to ['one', 'two']
});
```